# How to tell if a complex function has this property

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Suppose we have a complex function of a complex variable $f(z)$. How can we know if it satisfies (I don't know how to name this or type it in latex)

$$
\overline{f(z)}=f(\bar z)
$$

I tried linear functions, polynomials, exponentials and I got yes for some and no for others. For polynomials, all the coefficients must be real, for exponentials, the power has to be real and so on. So I came up with this idea: If you can write down the formula of the function without having to type $i$ then you get this property. If not, the LHS and the RHS of the equation above disagree. Any one have the answer to that? I guess It should be some kind of theorem, no?

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle

Answer (score 1):

Hint valid when $f$ is holomorphic: suppose
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z - c)^n.$$
Now apply your hypothesis and use the continuity of conjugation.

EDIT:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \overline{a_n}(\overline{z} - \overline{c})^n = \overline{\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z - c)^n} = \overline{f(z)} = f(\overline{z}) =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(\overline{z} - c)^n .$$
Now, we can reasonably suppose that $c\in\Bbb R$ (why?)...

Comment: Only if coefficients are not real. Consider $f(z)=i$.

Comment: Does that property have a name?

Comment: @spinosarus123 Note that the (only) coefficient of your example is not real. [Please explain what your comment means a little more-- thanks.]

Comment: But consider f(z)=i z. What happens there?

Comment: @coffeemath I meant, "It only holds if all coefficients are real. Consider $f(z)=i$."

Comment: @spinosarus123 Suppose we restrict ourselves to non-constant functions which is a special case. Then my claim is true no?

Comment: @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla I am afraid I don't see where continuity comes into play, could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: @plus1, power series are limits of finite sums.